# VBA Chart 3D Rotation

Tags: excel, vba, charts, formatting

I was wondering if someone could help me with a VBA macro I'm working on. I'm simply selecting an unformatted chart and doing some simple formatting. By default, it's a regular pie graph. I'm trying to make it into a 3D pie graph and change the X and Y rotations to 50 and 30 degrees respectively. I've recorded the macro using Excel but for some reason the 3D rotation isn't working. All of the other formatting works perfect; only this doesn't work. Any ideas on how I should proceed? Thanks

```
Sub Macro2()
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Topic Breakdown by Priority").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DPieExploded
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Topic Breakdown by Priority").ThreeD.RotationX = -50
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Topic Breakdown by Priority").ThreeD.RotationY = 30
End Sub
```

Comment: do you have your chart 3D or 2D. You need to have it 3D to make rotation...

Comment: The chart is 3D, I set that already. It still won't rotate using the macro for some reason.

Comment: If you right-click within chart area is `Rotation 3D` option enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm able to access the Rotation 3D menu and manually rotate the chart perfectly. But when I run the recorded macro it doesn't seem to do the rotation.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. The shape simply *doesn't* rotate from VBA command, and the Locals window reflects values of `0` for the `RotationX` and `RotationY` properties, despite previously setting them manually to `-50` and `30`, respectively.

Comment: I'd consider that a blessing. The only thing worse than a pie chart is a 3D pie chart. Read Stephen Few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set proper references to your chart. Based on your code it should go this way:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Topic Breakdown by Priority").Chart.ChartArea.Format.ThreeD.RotationX = -50
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Topic Breakdown by Priority").Chart.ChartArea.Format.ThreeD.RotationY = 30
```

Comment: Awesome! Yet another case of the macro recorder failing miserably :)